# `hostnamectl` ceased to display hardware info

Tags: updates, 23.04

After a recent (during the past one week) update on Ubuntu, now the `hostnamectl` command no longer displays system's hardware information. Previously its output was something like this:

```
 Static hostname: 
       Icon name: 
         Chassis: 
      Machine ID: 
         Boot ID: 
Operating System: 
          Kernel: 
    Architecture: 
 Hardware Vendor: 
  Hardware Model: 
Firmware Version:
```

Now it is:

```
 Static hostname:
       Icon name:
         Chassis:
      Machine ID:
         Boot ID:
Operating System:
          Kernel:
    Architecture:
Firmware Version:
```

The command `hostnamectl` itself does not seem to have been updated. Still in version **systemd 252 (252.5-2ubuntu3)**.

My system is a physical notebook and previously displayed hardware (Vendor and Model) information was just correct.

I cannot test right now, but the updates on `intel-microcode` or `linux-firmware` may be the cause.

Comment: I don't even get the line `Firmware Version:`. But also, why would you actually expect this from `hostnamectl`? I would think other commands was better suited for this.

Comment: hostnamectl (systemd 253.5-1) still works. (debian testing). The result may vary on how it was compiled. You could check this with `hostnamectl --version`